# Enter the wrong email address, the email will still go to the correct email address

Tags: laravel, smtp, gmail

If I am sending the email to "test+10@gmail.com", it will still send to "test@gmail.com"

Here is my code, please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$single_email = $this->single_email;
        try {
            Mail::send('welcome_mail',['user'=>$single_email], function($message) use($single_email) {
                
                $name = "Name";

                if($single_email->first_name){
                    $name = $single_email->first_name;
                }
                $message->to($single_email->email,$name)
                            ->subject("Subject")
                            ->from('from@gmail.com',"From")
                            ->replyTo('replyto@gmail.com',"Reply to");
            });
            MailSend::where('id',$single_email->id)->update(['is_sent'=>3]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            MailSend::where('id',$single_email->id)->update(['error'=>$e->getMessage()]);
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise

Comment: Some email services, GMail included, create mailbox aliases of the form `username+anythingYouLike@service.com` … so the email address isn't wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how emails work. Gmail and most providers allow you multiple "sibling" emails by appending + to the end. For example, test+1@gmail.com and test+stackoverflow@gmail.com will both end up at test@gmail.com - One of many things people use this is to track which service leaked your email. E.g. test+facebook@gmail.com, if you start getting spam emails to test+facebook@gmail.com, you will know they revealed it.

So, there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: That cleared up my confusion